# Prevent Post Request from setting certain values in Asp.Net Core 2.0 API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 API with a Contact model with the following fields:

`ID`, `Name`, `Company`, `ProfilePicFileName`, `Email`, `BirthDay`, `PhoneNumberWork`, `PhoneNumberHome`, `Address`.

A POST request allows the client to create a contact record. But it can also set values for `ID` and `ProfilePicFileName`, which I want to prevent.

How can I prevent post request from setting certain values (namely `ID` and `ProfilePicFileName`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I prevent post request from setting certain values(namely ID and ProfilePicFileName).

By creating a model specific to the action in question that excludes the unwanted properties.

```
public class ContactViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumberWork { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumberHome { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

That way the action will only have the desired properties populated by the model binder

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ContactViewModel contact) {
    //...
}
```

within the action the view model could be mapped back to the model.

Try to avoid using your persistence models as data transfer objects as it can leak data that was not meant to be sent over the wire. It can also expose vectors that allow additional data to be sent that was not intended to be sent.

Actions should only accept what is explicitly required (Explicit Dependency Principle). And should only expose what is necessary.

This way it does not matter what additional values are provided by the client. The model binder will only bind the necessary values.

Comment: thanks. Can you elaborate on why I should avoid using models a data transfer objects?

Comment: @MatiasMiraglio if for example you are using Entity Framework and you have foreign keys, it can have unwanted behavior in terms of what data is sent to the client when requested. As well as the current problem you are experiencing.

Comment: when the contact record is requested I do want to provide all of the data, including the ID, to the client. would it be ok in that situation to use the contact class? or should I create a contactViewModel that is identical to the contact model?

Comment: @MatiasMiraglio you could to be safe. But that would be a matter of choice.

Comment: is it ok to call them viewmodel and save them in the ViewModels folder? it's not really a viewmodel since I won't pass it to a view, I'll serve it directly from the controller.

Comment: Again a matter of choice. You can still think of them as models. Create a models folder and hold them there.